# How to get the content of first cell of a table using jquery if table is made using Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

The table being made dynamically using Thymeleaf. Each row of the table has a img link attached to it. On the click of which I want to get the selected rows img link first , second and third cell.

Relevant Table Code

```
<table class="table" id="tblDocType" style="padding: 20px 10px;">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
<th scope="col"> <b> Document Type </b></th>
<th scope="col"> <b> Practice Area </b> </th>
<th scope="col"><b> Retention Policy </b></th>
<th scope="col"> <b> Effective Date<br> Required </b></th>
<th scope="col"> <b> Termination Date<br> Required </b></th>
<th scope="col"> <b> Action</b></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr th:each="doctype,iterStat  : ${dlist}">
<td th:text = "${doctype?.doctypes}"></td>
<td th:text = "${doctype?.practiceAreaId}"></td>
<td th:text = "${doctype?.retention_policy}"></td>
<td th:text = "${doctype?.effectiveDateRequired}"></td>
<td th:text = "${doctype?.terminationDateRequired}"></td>
<td>
<a href="#" th:name="${doctype?.practiceAreaId}" th:id="${iterStat.index}" onclick="deleteTrigger(this.id)" style="color: blue;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to get the cell values using jquery.

Relevant jquery code

```
function deleteTrigger(id){
   var value=$("#tblDocType").closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
   console.log("value=",value);
   var doctypesjson={
          "doctypes": id,
          "practiceAreaId": pracaticeareaidfrombutton     
  };
}
```

In the console the value is coming blank.

Please help me if you know what can be done for the problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your title is quite different to your question. Can I clarify that you want to get the first cell of a row when clicked, and then subsequently the second and third cells specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Presently, it appears that your code is looking for the **first** **TR**, then within that the first **TD**. However, this won’t do anything as your first TR only contains **TH**.

In calling your deleteTrigger() function, you should pass through the element that was clicked

```
deleteTrigger(this); // use this for your TR lookup.
```

However, since you’re using jQuery already, it may make your life easier to abandon the delete function altogether and use a listener;

```
$(“tr”).click(function(){
  $(this).find(“td”).first() // this will get the first td of a clicked row
  $(this).find(“td”).eq(1) // this will get second td etc...
})
```

Comment: This is not working. I am still getting blank value in the console